# Python running SQL statement in threaded timer

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, timer

I am trying to run a SQL statement every minute, but I need to be able to iterate through incoming data as well continuously. So I have made a thread timer that I found with the help of another SO question, but I am receiving the following error when trying to run it. What are some solutions to this?

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 18460 and this is thread id 29296
```

Here is a sample of the timer code. I am using a update every second here for testing purposes only.

```
def update():
    threading.Timer(1.0, update).start()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET timer = timer + 1")
    db.commit()
    print("Updating all timers")
update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work by putting the connection in the same thread. If you do it every minute I suppose its ok. Making a connection every second seems a bit expensive though.

```
def update():
    threading.Timer(1.0, update).start()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET timer = timer + 1")
    conn.commit()
    print("Updating all timers")
update()
```

To answer your question of ‘why’. I think it is because your connection is on the main thread and your commit to the connection is on another. Hope this is correct and I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that last night but was still getting the same error, I must have just messed up somewhere. The update will only be every minute at most, most likely even less so it shouldn't be a problem.